# Which elm package versions are installed?

Tags: elm, package-managers

`elm-package` can manage dependencies for elm, but the only commands it supports (as of version 0.18.0) are `install`, `publish`, `bump` and `diff` according to running it without arguments. I was expecting something like `elm-package list` to show the installed packages.

Is there a command to list the currently installed elm package versions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is no one, but you can execute `tree elm-stuff/packages -L 3 --noreport` in your command line.

You will get a tree like this:

```
elm-stuff/packages
├── debois
│   ├── elm-dom
│   │   └── 1.2.3
│   └── elm-mdl
│       └── 8.1.0
├── elm-lang
│   ├── core
│   │   └── 5.1.1
│   ├── dom
│   │   └── 1.1.1
│   ├── html
│   │   └── 2.0.0
│   ├── http
│   │   └── 1.0.0
│   ├── mouse
│   │   └── 1.0.1
│   ├── virtual-dom
│   │   └── 2.0.4
│   └── window
│       └── 1.0.1
├── mgold
│   └── elm-date-format
│       └── 1.2.0
└── thaterikperson
    └── elm-strftime
```

You can also just do `cat elm-stuff/exact-dependencies.json`, but there is no guarantee of have them installed:

```
{
    "debois/elm-mdl": "8.1.0",
    "elm-lang/virtual-dom": "2.0.4",
    "elm-lang/mouse": "1.0.1",
    "mgold/elm-date-format": "1.2.0",
    "elm-lang/dom": "1.1.1",
    "elm-lang/html": "2.0.0",
    "elm-lang/http": "1.0.0",
    "debois/elm-dom": "1.2.3",
    "elm-lang/window": "1.0.1",
    "elm-lang/core": "5.1.1"
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is the best there is right now. It's a shame tree isn't cross-platform (not for Windows, available for OSX).

Comment: but it should work now that Windows 10 comes with bash, shouldn't it?

Comment: 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' is still beta (at time of writing - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/commandline/wsl/install_guide), but probably.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Lighttable editor with the elm-light plug in then you would have a command to show (and add) packages.